# Loop in bash from 0.01 to 0.5

Tags: bash, loops, decimal, weka

I am creating a script in bash to call a command 100 times, varying a float parameter each time. I need to call it with 0.01, then 0.02, 0.03 up to 0.5. As I cannot create a loop using a float in the condition or in the step I am not sure of how to do it. I tried doing the loop from 1 to 50 and then inside dividing the number by 100, transforming that into a float, and calling the command with that, but then the command (basically I am calling Weka and the number corresponds to the confidence interval) doesn't recognize the parameter correctly so maybe I am using the wrong datatype.

Thanks in advance!
Patricio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for i in `seq 0.01 0.01 0.5`; do  echo "called with $i" ; done
```

this will create a seq of 0.01 to 0.5 in increment of 0.01. So replace the `echo` with your needed call.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot use the solution proposed by [abasu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16587466/1630171) (+1) you could try something like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 50`; do
  n=$(echo $i | awk '{printf "%.2f", $1 / 100}')
  echo $n
done
```

or like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 50`; do
  n=$(printf "0.%02d" $i)
  echo $n
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq 0.01 0.01 0.5);do
...
done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.